# PHP code on curl

Tags: php, curl

THis code is not showing up the google home page. Please point out the error in it.

```
    <?php
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com.kw");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    print $result;
    ?>
```

Comment: Google restricted its access by curl

Comment: This works fine for me. Can you make outbound connections to port 443 **from your server**?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that if your response is string-based; *curl automatically encodes the response in utf8.* So it might be necessary to decode the String to get what you want. Otherwise, your code is OK but here is another variant:

```
    <?php

        $serviceURL = "https://www.google.com.kw";
        $curl       = curl_init();

        $settings   = array(
            CURLOPT_URL             => $serviceURL,
            CURLOPT_POST            => false,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        );

        curl_setopt_array($curl, $settings);
        $response   = curl_exec($curl);
        $response   = utf8_decode ( $response );    // <== DECODES THE UTF8 ENCODED STRING.


        if(curl_errno($curl)){
            var_dump( curl_error($curl) );
            exit;
        }

        print($response);

        curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
$curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.co.in");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/plain'));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate'));
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_ENCODING, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        print  $result;
```